# Computational complexities in factoring

Tags: complexity-classes, cr.crypto-security, factoring, primes

[Note: n is a given integer (not the number of its digits)]

I'd like to know how O(sqrt(n)/log(n)) would compare against the computational complexity of the best available algorithms (as well as the other one available) for factoring.

Is it conceivable to think that since there are $\sqrt n/\log(\sqrt n) $ primes smaller than $\sqrt n$, in intuitive terms the above complexity could actually represent a lower limit that cannot be broken ? (This would correspond to the ideal situation where all primes were already available (precomputed) and readily accessible at no computational cost.)

After all the information about the divisibility for a given prime does not seem to suggest anything about the divisibility for any other one, and there seems to be no shared information. Or is this thought wrong ? If yes, which is, in intuitive terms clearly, a more plausible candidate for a (larger) lower bound for the factoring complexity?

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this. We have migrated your question to [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the intuitive observation "There are about $\sqrt{n}$ prime factors to try" does *not* imply a lower bound on the complexity of factoring.  There is absolutely no reason that a factoring algorithm must try every possible prime factor, or even that the algorithm's behavior should resemble "trying" different factors at all.

Even though *precisely* the same intuitive argument can be applied to checking whether a number is prime, the [AKS primality-testing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test) runs in $\log^{O(1)} n$ time.

Comment: Thank you Jeff. Beautiful intuition. A quality missing in many nowadays scientists. In particular, I wished to know, setting P(n) = sqrt(n)/log(sqrt(n)) and indicating by O(B(n)) the complexity of the best available factoring method, the order of the ratio B(n) / P(n). In intuitive terms: how much better is the best method with respect to O(P(n)) ?

Comment: see wiki for references for some algorithms with running time $\exp(O(\sqrt{log n \log \log n}))$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#General-purpose

Comment: Is that much better than O(sqrt(n)/log(sqrt(n))) ? How much better exactly? (Remember that with n I am denoting the number itself, not the number of digits)

Comment: It's less than $O(n^{\alpha})$ for any constant $\alpha$. So yes, much better, asymptotically. BTW this is a pretty basic question, and [CS@se](http://cs.stackexchange.com) is better suited for those

Comment: Thank you, I see, but does actually exists a constant \alpha such that O(sqrt(n)/log(sqrt(n))) is asymptotically greater than O(n^{\alpha}). What value of \alpha is that (it seems that \alpha = 1/2 would not be small enough) ?

Comment: Take $\alpha = 0.4999999999999999999999$, for example.

Comment: Thank you. I get it. For a last doubt, is there any reference for a simple proof of "It's less than $O(n^\alpha)$ for any constant $\alpha$"

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log n/n^c = 0$ for any constant $c>0$ follows immediately from L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Actually I was referring to your sentence about $\exp(O(\sqrt{log n \log \log n}))$ being less than $O(n^{\alpha})$ (or do you mean that $exp()$ and $O()$ can be interchanged and a similar argument applies ?)

Comment: they cannot be interchanged, but $n^\alpha = \exp(\alpha \log n)$. take the limit of $\exp(C \sqrt{\log n \log \log n} - \alpha \log n)$ as $n \to \infty$ for any constants $C$ and $\alpha$.